# last EditText line disappears

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a number of data entry screens in my app. In each of them, the last EditText on the screen does not display. It is usable in that you can press in it and type text, but it should be visible also.
Here is the code for one of the screens:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pdrestimator.Main_Activity$Car_Fragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vinLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="VIN" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/carVinLabel"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vinLabel"
            android:ems="10" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yearLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vinLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Year" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/yearLabel"
            android:ems="10" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/makeLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yearLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Make" />


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/make"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/makeLabel"
            android:ems="10" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/modelLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/makeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Model" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/model"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/modelLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/modelLabel"
            android:ems="10" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/colorLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/modelLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Color" />


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colorLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/colorLabel"
            android:ems="10" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/colorLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Manuf. Date" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/manufactureDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
            android:ems="10" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Stock Number" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/stockNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
            android:ems="10" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you click on the EditText if its not visible?

Comment: I know where it should be: to the right of it's label, directly below and lined up with the EditText above it. It's there, but the line where the cursor rests is not displaying.

Comment: Can you post the `EditText` xml which are visible to you?

Comment: I can, but there is no substantive difference between them and the one posted above. If, for instance, I remove the stock number field mentioned above entirely, the EditText currently above it will now be invisible.

Comment: Please post the complete xml, then I can try here

Comment: I edited the original posting with the complete code for one of the screens. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: See my answer. Compare the chages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/stockNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
            android:ems="10" />
```

layout_alignBottom instead of baseline does the trick!

[Worth looking at this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignBaseline)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.pdrestimator.Main_Activity$Car_Fragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vinLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="VIN" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vinLabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vinLabel"
        android:ems="10" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vinLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Year" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:ems="10" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/makeLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Make" />


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/make"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/makeLabel"
        android:ems="10" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modelLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/makeLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Model" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/model"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/modelLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/modelLabel"
        android:ems="10" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colorLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/modelLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Color" />


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colorLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/colorLabel"
        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/colorLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Manuf. Date" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/manufactureDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/manufactureDateLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Stock Number" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stockNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stockNumberLabel"
        android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this did not work. The line for the bottom EditText is still not visible.

Comment: When you tried it on your system with my original code, did the EditText display?

Comment: Its visible here. I tried it here. Try replacing the complete xml.

Comment: I created a separate XML file, but it appeared the same.